# Elementary graphics in java/scala

Tags: scala, graphics

I'd like to add a real-time graphical representation of what's going on behind some scala code. Just a black window of a given size where I can put colored pixels at random (x, y) points will do. That's exactly want I'll be doing, actually.

What library should I use? I want to stay as simple as possible, so as to avoid mixing in (say) a full-fledged game-writing library just for a quick and dirty way to place pixels on a canvas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd just use the Java [2D Graphics API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/).

Scala has support for Java's Swing GUI API, see the `scala.swing` package in the Scala API documentation.

Comment: I was taking a look at that while I waited for answers :) I'm drawing rectangles in a swing panel. Just what I wanted. Thanks! Will accept the answer as soon as I can for future reference